# solve equation in python with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to solve an equation in python but I keep getting this error:

```
__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

and my code is as below:

```
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
x,y,z = sym.symbols('x,y,z')

c1 = sym.Symbol('c1')

f=sym.Eq(2*x**2+y+z,1)

g=sym.Eq(x+2*y+z,c1)

h=sym.Eq(-2*x+y,-z)

sym.solve([f,g,h],(x,y,z))
```

Comment: I ran your code and [I'm getting a solution](https://i.imgur.com/737NCKz.png). Are you sure this is the code you ran when you got the error? Also, at which line was this error thrown? Alternatively you could try to upgrade to the latest SymPy like this `pip3 install --user --upgrade sympy` and rerun your code.

Comment: When asking about an error, you should show the full traceback.  WIthout it we don't know which line is causing the problem (and apparently you do't either!).

Comment: This error can be seen if you call `Symbol()` with no arguments. That won't come from the code shown so I think that you have that somewhere else in the code you are running